# CLDR right unicode is giving me the wrong symbol

Tags: unicode, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, cldr

I'm currently trying to change the currency symbol for the south korean won in my prestashop 1.7.3.4 installation to the hangeul version, that just reads "won" (원). Which is more commonly used than ₩. Prestashop uses unicode for these. The default value in

main--ko-KR-currencies is:

```
"KRW":{"displayName":"\ub300\ud55c\ubbfc\uad6d \uc6d0","displayName-count-other":"\ub300\ud55c\ubbfc\uad6d \uc6d0","symbol":"\u20a9","symbol-alt-narrow":"\u20a9"}
```

and in main--ko-KR-numbers is:

```
{"main":{"ko-KR":{"identity":{"version":{"_cldrVersion":"26","_number":"$Revision: 10669 $"},"generation":{"_date":"$Date: 2014-07-23 16:10:33 -0500 (Wed, 23 Jul 2014) $"},"language":"ko","territory":"KR"},"numbers":{"defaultNumberingSystem":"latn","otherNumberingSystems":{"native":"latn"},"minimumGroupingDigits":"1","symbols-numberSystem-latn":{"decimal":".","group":",","list":";","percentSign":"%","plusSign":"+","minusSign":"-","exponential":"E","superscriptingExponent":"\u00d7","perMille":"\u2030","infinity":"\u221e","nan":"NaN","timeSeparator":":"},"decimalFormats-numberSystem-latn":{"standard":"#,##0.###","long":{"decimalFormat":{"1000-count-other":"0000","10000-count-other":"0\ub9cc","100000-count-other":"00\ub9cc","1000000-count-other":"000\ub9cc","10000000-count-other":"0000\ub9cc","100000000-count-other":"0\uc5b5","1000000000-count-other":"00\uc5b5","10000000000-count-other":"000\uc5b5","100000000000-count-other":"0000\uc5b5","1000000000000-count-other":"0\uc870","10000000000000-count-other":"00\uc870","100000000000000-count-other":"000\uc870"}},"short":{"decimalFormat":{"1000-count-other":"0000","10000-count-other":"0\ub9cc","100000-count-other":"00\ub9cc","1000000-count-other":"000\ub9cc","10000000-count-other":"0000\ub9cc","100000000-count-other":"0\uc5b5","1000000000-count-other":"00\uc5b5","10000000000-count-other":"000\uc5b5","100000000000-count-other":"0000\uc5b5","1000000000000-count-other":"0\uc870","10000000000000-count-other":"00\uc870","100000000000000-count-other":"000\uc870"}}},"scientificFormats-numberSystem-latn":{"standard":"#E0"},"percentFormats-numberSystem-latn":{"standard":"#,##0%"},"currencyFormats-numberSystem-latn":{"currencySpacing":{"beforeCurrency":{"currencyMatch":"[:^S:]","surroundingMatch":"[:digit:]","insertBetween":"\u00a0"},"afterCurrency":{"currencyMatch":"[:^S:]","surroundingMatch":"[:digit:]","insertBetween":"\u00a0"}},"accounting":"\u00a4#,##0.00;(\u00a4#,##0.00)","standard":"#,##0.00\u00a4","unitPattern-count-other":"{0} {1}"},"miscPatterns-numberSystem-latn":{"atLeast":"{0}+","range":"{0}-{1}"}}}}}
```

With emphasize on:

```
"percentFormats-numberSystem-latn":{"standard":"#,##0%"},"currencyFormats-numberSystem-latn":{"currencySpacing":{"beforeCurrency":{"currencyMatch":"[:^S:]","surroundingMatch":"[:digit:]","insertBetween":"\u00a0"},"afterCurrency":{"currencyMatch":"[:^S:]","surroundingMatch":"[:digit:]","insertBetween":"\u00a0"}},"accounting":"\u00a4#,##0.00;(\u00a4#,##0.00)","standard":"#,##0.00\u00a4","unitPattern-count-other":"{0} {1}"},"miscPatterns-numberSystem-latn":{"atLeast":"{0}+","range":"{0}-{1}"}}}}}
```

According to my research:

u20A9 = ₩

uc6d0 = 원

But as we can see, the main--ko-KR-currencies file alreads uses uc6d0 and it gets displayed as ₩.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line, try changing

```
"symbol":"\u20a9","symbol-alt-narrow":"\u20a9"
```

to

```
"symbol":"\uc6d0","symbol-alt-narrow":"\uc6d0"
```